# Date and time format automatically changes to text

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need your assistance in downloading outlook mail data into a specific access table field in time format hh:mm. Below code works well and I have formatted the table field which is estml in hh:mm format. 
Issue 1) This code is triggered by a timer. When the timer runs data gets imported but estml field property automatically changes into text and estimate value is stored as text.
Issue 2) major issue is when I run a query which should show estimate > 7 hrs. Query is not deriving correct results since data is stored as text. 
Issue 3) the estimate can be more than 24 hrs say 75 hrs. Still the field should capture 75 hrs.

```
Private Sub getml()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application

Dim inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim inboxItems As Outlook.Items
Dim Mailobject As Object
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim dealer As Integer
Set db = CurrentDb

Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set inbox = OlApp.GetNamespace("Mapi").GetDefaultFolder(olFold erInbox)
Set rst= CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("mls")
Set inboxItems = inbox.Items
For Each Mailobject In inboxItems

With rst
.AddNew
!task= Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("taskID")
!estml= Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("estimate")
.Update

Mailobject.UnRead = False
End With
End If
Next
Set OlApp = Nothing
Set inbox = Nothing
Set inboxItems = Nothing
Set Mailobject = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Which data type is field `estml` in table `mls`?  My guess would be **Short Text** or **Long Text** (instead of **Date/Time**).

Comment: estml field is having data type as date/time

Comment: Why do you think it's stored as text?  Regardless, try: `!estml= Val(Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("estimate"))`

Comment: After the timer runs the code if I cross check the field format it automatically changes to text. However I will try the solution you have given and confirm.

Comment: The field format in the table changes?  I think you're misunderstanding something.  It might **display** as a different date format, but if the field's data type is `Date/Time` then it's not changing to text.

Comment: ...perhaps it would be helpful if you could share a screenshot of the issue **and** of the table's *design* view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>To follow-up on my comments (above)...</sup>

You're saying that, in table `mls`, field `estml` has :

- **Data Type** set to `Date/Time`, and,
- **Format** set to `hh:mm`

...but yet you say:

> *"Query is not deriving correct results since data is stored as text."*

This doesn't make sense.  If the Data Type is definately set to `Date/Time`, it's not going to spontaneously change to Text.

It might ***display*** differently elsewhere, since the ***Format*** applies to the *table*, not necessarily the entire database, but the Data Type will not change.

To confirm that the field is stored as text (and that you're seeing the actual unformatted data), ensure the table is setup correctly like by double checking the **Data Type** *and* removing any existing **Format** like this:

[image: example reset data type]

If your issue is still not resolved, you'll need to share some more information, such as screenshots of both your issue ***and*** the table design view.

Answer (score 2):

Many misunderstandings here.

1. The format of *estml* is of no importance for the values. It is for display only.
2. If *estml* is of data type *Date*, then *estml field property automatically changes into text and estimate value is stored as text* cannot happen. Neither cannot this: *Query is not deriving correct results since data is stored as text*
3. If `Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("estimate")` returns text, convert this to a date value.
4. *the estimate can be more than 24 hrs say 75 hrs.* That is possible, but it cannot be displayed like 75 hours natively - 23:59:59 is the maximum.

Ad. 3:

```
!estml= TimeValue(Mailobject.UserProperties.Find("estimate"))
```

Ad. 4:

You can use this function for display of hours (and minutes):

```
Public Function FormatHourMinute( _
  ByVal datTime As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparator As String = ":") _
  As String

' Returns count of days, hours and minutes of datTime
' converted to hours and minutes as a formatted string
' with an optional choice of time separator.
'
' Example:
'   datTime: #10:03# + #20:01#
'   returns: 30:04
'
' 2005-02-05. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim strHour       As String
  Dim strMinute     As String
  Dim strHourMinute As String

  strHour = CStr(Fix(datTime) * 24 + Hour(datTime))
  ' Add leading zero to minute count when needed.
  strMinute = Right("0" & CStr(Minute(datTime)), 2)
  strHourMinute = strHour & strSeparator & strMinute

  FormatHourMinute = strHourMinute

End Function
```